# Query about cubic roots and the discriminant

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I have an equation a little like this;

$$2c^3 - 3oc^2 + oG = 0$$

In my equations, $o$ is always $> G$ . I'm trying to find a general solution rather than constantly estimating it graphically, and I got onto the Wikipedia article on cubic equations. If I've done my algebra correctly, the discriminant is $\operatorname{Dis} = 108(G^2\cdot o^2)(o^2 - G^2)$ which is always real and positive, meaning there should be three real solutions.

My problem is this however; there is a square root term that is $-27(2)\cdot \operatorname{Dis}$ ; this will always be negative, and always give a pair of complex roots; worse, I then have to take the cubic root of this at least twice; this is throwing me and I don't know how to explicitly solve the equation, or find a general form?

Can anyone help or point out any mistakes I'm making ? I'd be most grateful!

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Check this out this paper [Savante Janson on Roots of Polynomials of Degree 3 and 4](http://www2.math.uu.se/~svante/papers/sjN7.pdf). Also try the recently posted answer for Stack Exchange Question [145590](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145590/help-with-cardanos-formula). These may lead you in a good direction.

Comment: Thanks Tim - seems I'm stuck with an ugly looking expression to try and solve..I'll have at it for now!