# Issue in the solution of general cubic equation.

Tags: polynomials

*This is in continuance to my earlier post : [Deriving expression for general cubic equation solution.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2755914/424260) Also, the links are repeated for the first four pages of the book by Dickson, titled "Introduction to Theory of Algebraic Equations" are given as : [page #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxfIg.png),$\,$[page #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKF8J.png),$\,$ [page #3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mw7eW.png), $\,$[page #4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drat4.png).$\,$ Added are rest $5$ pages (#$5$ to #$9$) from first chapter of the book : [page #5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDino.png), $\,$ [page #6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqLBx.png),$\,$ [page #7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccY6J.png),$\,$ [page #8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDXTS.png),$\,$ [page #9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRoVJ.png).*

On page $4$, the book states that: "Aside from the factor 1/3, the roots of the sextic ($5$) (i.e, $z^6 +qz^3 -\frac{p^3}{27}=0$) are $\cdots$"
But, how the value 1/3 is a root of the sextic (5) is not clear.

I will be putting stated factor $\frac{1}{3}$ in equation $(5)$ to get: 
$(\frac{1}{3})^6 +q(\frac{1}{3})^3 -\frac{p^3}{27}=0 => \frac{1}{27^2} +q(\frac{1}{27})- \frac{p^3}{27} = 0$

The values of $p =c_2 - \frac{1}{3} c_1^2 , q = -c_3+\frac{1}{3}c_1c_2 -\frac{2}{27}c_1^3$ are of constants and are dependent only on the coefficients of the general cubic equation (stated on page $1$ as : $x^3 -c_1x^2 +c_2x +c_3=0$), hence cannot be simplified further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't mean that $\frac13$ is the root of the cubic equation.

We already know that $$z^3 =-\frac12q\pm\sqrt{R}$$

and $$\sqrt[3]{-\frac12q+\sqrt{R}}=\color{blue}{\frac13}\left(y_1+\omega^2y_2+\omega y_3 \right)=\color{blue}{\frac13}\left(x_1+\omega^2x_2+\omega x_3 \right)$$

What it meant is that $\frac13 \psi_i$ are the roots of $$z^6+qz^3-\frac{p^3}{27}=0.$$

Comment: Thanks, and would request you to state any reason for Hudde substitution (on page #$2$ of the book, $y = z - \frac{p}{3z}$) that specifically uses $p$, that I hope stands for $p=c_2 -\frac{1}{3}c_1^2\implies y= z-\frac{(x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_3x_1)-\frac{1}{3}(x_1+x_2+x_3)^2}{3z}$$\implies y = z -\frac{x_1(x_2-x_1)+x_3(x_1-x_3)+x_2(x_3-x_2)}{3z}$. In my all questions so far, I have not been aware of this issue, and the book sidelines it too.

Comment: my current understanding of the approach is superficial. I am waiting for a cool answer as well. I can't see it.

Comment: Kindly find a new post on this issue at : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2764553/424260. Kindly suggest edits, if needed.

Comment: Have found some simple reference to Hudde's substitution in a book  titled : Patterns of Change: Linguistic Innovations in the Development of Classical ... By Ladislav Kvaszin, in $4$ pages, may be it helps somewhat. The $4$ pages of concern are (i) page 177-178: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJaAX.png; (ii) page 179-180:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/if9sD.png
It comes quite near in pointing out 'clearly' on page #$178$ in the quadratic form, the product of the two factors, i.e. $c_2$ is same as the cube root of last term ($\frac{-p}{3}$).

Comment: Want to clarify that apart from a general explanation of Hudde's substitution, the last comment, has 'no' concern with the latest problem as stated earlier. Also, I hope that a new page ($366$) from the book : Algebra in the mirrors of mathematics, by Gabriel Katz may help in some improvement in understanding of the workings of the cardano's formula for cubic:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LPcT.png. In fact, it seems that Hudde made a guess to make things work, and the logic (as in my first comment) can be shown only by curve drawing.

Comment: Sorry, not worthy of separate question. Want plot points $M,H,C,R,A,B$ in paper: http://i.stack.imgur.com/EVRu1.png, in desmos: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/m7kgvinue1, with analysis: $(i)$ Need two points for some secant line (that will help form parametric tangent/secant line for curve) with $y'=0$ for $x_i=\pm 2$, (ii) $y_i= -6,-2$, with slope of secant between first ($H$) & second cusp (let $Z$) with slope $=-1$  & eqn. of secant as $y=-x+c$. That did not work. Seems need parametric curve with two initial points:$(i) R, y=0$,(ii)$H$. So I need Cardano's formula to get $x$ for $R$?

Comment: depending on your purpose, there isn't a need to do everything exactly, as we can read off the coordinate of $R$ from your current plot.

Comment: I am sorry for not stating the problem correctly. I want to plot a parametric curve that will be able to draw secant, tangent depending on some parameter.

Comment: sure, you can use Cardano.

Comment: Please see my posts at: (1) https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2804677/424260. I am confused with reason shown in my last comment to the OP, and to the highest voted answer.(2) https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2805021/424260. This is about using the Viete formula to solve the equation.