# Logical significance of Hudde's substitution in solution of general cubic equation

Tags: polynomials

*This is in continuance to my earlier post : [Deriving expression for general cubic equation solution.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2755914/424260) Also, the links are repeated for the first four pages of the book by Dickson, titled "Introduction to Theory of Algebraic Equations" are given as : [page #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxfIg.png),$\,$[page #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKF8J.png),$\,$ [page #3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mw7eW.png), $\,$[page #4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drat4.png).$\,$ Added are rest $5$ pages (#$5$ to #$9$) from first chapter of the book : [page #5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDino.png), $\,$ [page #6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqLBx.png),$\,$ [page #7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccY6J.png),$\,$ [page #8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDXTS.png),$\,$ [page #9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRoVJ.png).*

On page $2$ of the book, the Hudde substitution ($y = z - \frac{p}{3z}$) specifically uses $p$, that stands for 
$$p=c_2 -\frac{1}{3}c_1^2$$$$\implies y= z-\frac{(x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_3x_1)-\frac{1}{3}(x_1+x_2+x_3)^2}{3z}$$$$\implies y = z -\frac{x_1(x_2-x_1)+x_3(x_1-x_3)+x_2(x_3-x_2)}{3z}$$$$\implies y = z +\frac{x_1(x_1-x_2)+x_3(x_3-x_1)+x_2(x_2-x_3)}{3z}$$ The book sidelines the issue, and am not aware of any source that gives details about its significance.