# If $a\in \mathbb{R}$, then solve $x + a^3 = \sqrt[3]{a-x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

If $a\in \mathbb{R}$, then show $$x + a^3 = \sqrt[3]{a-x}$$

I am a newbie to such questions, that seem more like transformation of one form to another. But, can take a more elegant form by using the recursiveness (*could not find a better word*) as follows:

$a = \sqrt[3]{\sqrt[3]{a-x}-x}$

Also, can define the function : 
$f(f(a))=f(\sqrt[3]{a-x}) = \sqrt[3]{\sqrt[3]{a-x}-x}$

Now, need form a relation between $f(a)$ & $a$. But, how is not clear.

Comment: What happens when $a=0$?

Comment: @Topology Do you mean that at $a=0$ there is no mapping possible by nested function. If so, please elaborate.

Comment: Do you need to solve the equation or just show that it has solutions?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Both, but showing that solution exists is taken by me as a preliminary step.

Comment: Showing that there is one unique solution is easy since one function is bijective increasing and the other bijective decreasing. But in fact you have a great answer by @ChristianF below.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I could not gather which is bijective increasing, & which one is bijective decreasing. May be your intent is shown up in the answer stated by you, but not clear to me. Please elaborate.

Comment: $x+\text{constant}$ is bijective increasing, $\sqrt[3]{\text{constant}-x}$ is bijective decreasing.

Comment: You need to clarify the question, because as written it's nonsense. It's impossible to show $x + a^3 = \sqrt[3]{a-x}$ iif $a\in\Bbb R$, because it simply doesn't follow. For example let $x=a=1$. If the problem is actually to _solve_ that equation then say so!

Comment: @ArnaudMortier By stating that it is easy to show that unique soln. exists, do you mean that the only solution is where the two functions concur. But, how to show by some technique that both functions have a common value. I hope you have shown only the uniqueness of the common solution only. Please place an answer for all this.

Comment: prove or disprove the following: if $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous increasing bijection function and $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous decreasing bijection function. then $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$ is a bijection function.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh Am not good at analysis, & am thankful (as usual) for goading me to improve. Have put a post, as it was coming into 2-3 comments for one response only. It is at : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2805719/424260. I have got response, but the significance of 'proving' (as per the answer there) to this question & the highest voted answer is not clear at all. The reason is that here the two functions have been proved to have only one unique point in common as common domain.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh Please see my post for intuitively seeing that the G.F. for having not more than $k$ objects is given by : $\frac{1-x^{k+1}}{1-x}$. It is at : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2806009/424260.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh My second last comment is in response to your question, so expect vetting of my post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $t=\sqrt[3]{a-x}$, then we can rewrite equation like this:

$$a-t^3+a^3 = t\implies (a-t)(a^2+at+t^2) +(a-t)=0 $$
so $t=a$, since $a^2+at+t^2 +1 >0$. Now we have $$x=a-a^3$$

Comment: Very nice... +1

Comment: could not gather how $a-t^3 +a^3 =t$. Stumbling too much here.

Comment: $t^3 =a-x$ so $x=a-t^3$

Comment: You seem to have manipulated to achieve the goal of having the bijective (*although cannot prove it, or think of a way for that*) monotonically increasing function form. I am stating this in context of @ArnaudMortier comment to the OP.

Comment: he has simplifed the expression until $(a-t)(a^2+at+t^2+1)=0$, since $a^2+at+t^2+1>0$, he can divide that term on both sides and we are left with $a-t=0$. An alternative view is once you have $a^3+a=t^3+t$, check that $x^3+x$ is an increasing function.

Answer (score 1):

Making $a-x = y^3$

$$
a-x = y^3\\
x+a^3 = y
$$

adding both equations

$$
a+a^3 = y + y^3 \Rightarrow a = y \Rightarrow x = a-a^3
$$

Comment: And this is because the function $x\to(x+x^3)$ is increasing, thus invertible.

Comment: First implication is non trivial. In order to use it you must prove that map $x\to x+x^3$ is injective.

Comment: It is injective because $(x+x^3)'=1+3x^2 \ne 0$

Comment: It is injective because it is the sum of two increasing functions

Answer (score 0):

Instead of cuberooting, cube.

So try:
$$(x+a^3)^3=a-x$$
$$x^3+3a^3x^2+3a^6x+a^9=a-x$$
$$x^3+3a^3x^2+(3a^6+1)x+(a^9-a)=0$$

Comment: Then factor out $x+a^3-a$.

Comment: @J.G. It does not seem obvious / trivial to think of factoring out $x+ a^3-a$ that I hope means that a root is $x=a−a^3$. There must be a way to get the root without knowing the answer beforehand.

Comment: @jiten ChristianF's is the best. The interesting consequence of such a factorisation would be to find the "fictional" roots of the quadratic factor.

Comment: In fact, I find the quadratic is $x^2+(2a^3+a)x+a^6+a^4+a^2+1$, making the complex roots $a^3-\frac{a}{2}\pm i\sqrt{\frac{3a^2}{4}+1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Substituting $y=\sqrt[3]{a-x}$, and thus $x = a - y^3$, we get

$$a - y^3 + a^3=y$$

Ordering

$$y^3 - y = a^3 - a$$

Thus, $y=a$ is a solution. And, if you have a 3rd degree polynom with a known root, you know what follows. :-)