# Cubic root in a quadratic number field

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, roots, extension-field, cubics

Suppose we are given an element $\alpha = a+b\sqrt{d}$ in the quadratic number field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$, where $a$, $b$ and $d$ are all rationals and $d$ does not have a rational square root. I want to test whether $\alpha = \beta^3$, for some $\beta \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$.

Using the technique mentioned in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/550121/denesting-phi-denesting-cube-roots?noredirect=1&lq=1) post, one can reduce the above problem to testing whether a suitable cubic equation over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ has a rational root or not. One can solve  that by factoring the cubic polynomial over rational field using the LLL algorithm. But, I do not wish to invoke that big machinery and was wondering if there is an easier and a direct way to decide whether an element has a cubic root in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$, without reducing it to the corresponding cubic equation.

Comment: If you have a cubic with rational coefficients, and you want to know whether it has a rational root, the rational root test should do that for you, with no need to invoke LLL.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, I agree. However rational root test involves factoring the leading coefficients, which is computationally inefficient as we believe integer factoring to be hard. LLL however, works in time, polynomial in the bit-size of coefficients of the cubic.