# I don't understand how to factor the expressions $\sqrt{57+40\sqrt2} - \sqrt{57-40\sqrt2}$

Tags: radicals, factoring

$\sqrt{57+40\sqrt2} - \sqrt{57-40\sqrt2}$

I'm completely clueless about how to use the formula $a^2 + 2ab + b^2 = (a+b)^2$ to factor the expressions.

With the help of commenters, I successfully factored the expressions.

$\sqrt{57+40\sqrt{2}} = 5+4\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{57-40\sqrt{2}} = 5-4\sqrt{2}$. $5+4\sqrt{2}-4\sqrt{2}+5=10$.

Comment: [A past answer I made a while ago will probably be helpful, if just in a more general sense.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/550121/denesting-phi-denesting-cube-roots/4502317#4502317)

Comment: $$(a+b\sqrt2)^2 = a^2+2ab\sqrt2+2b^2 = (a^2+2b^2) +2ab\sqrt2.$$  Can you find two numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $a^2+2b^2=57$ and $2ab=40$?

Comment: If you are trying to simplify $x=\sqrt{57+40\sqrt2} - \sqrt{57-40\sqrt2}$, you can try to factor $57+40\sqrt{2}$ as @Rócherz explained. Alternatively, you can compute $x^2$ and use identities.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  The reason your question has received down votes is that you have not included your attempt.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: For future reference, you might want to read our guidelines for how to [avoid "I'm completely clueless" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sqrt{57+40\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{25+40\sqrt{2}+32}=\sqrt{5^2+2\cdot 5\cdot 4\sqrt{2}+(4\sqrt{2})^2}=\sqrt{(5+4\sqrt{2})^2}=5+4\sqrt{2}$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt{57+40\sqrt2} - \sqrt{57-40\sqrt2}
$$
$$\Rightarrow \sqrt{25+32+2.(5).(4\sqrt2}) - \sqrt{25+32-2.(5).(4\sqrt2)}$$
$$\Rightarrow 5+4\sqrt2 - (4\sqrt2-5)$$
$$\Rightarrow 10$$

Comment: Your answer is incorrect. $5 - 4\sqrt{2} = \sqrt{25} - \sqrt{32} < 0$.  Therefore, it cannot be the square root of $\sqrt{57 - 40\sqrt{2}}$.

Answer (score 0):

In general, when asked to simplify an expression of the form
$$z:=\sqrt{x+a\surd y}\pm\sqrt{x-a\surd y},$$
the trick is to square it, and see what happens. Thus $z^2=\left(\sqrt{x+a\surd y}\pm\sqrt{x-a\surd y}\right)^2$, and so
$$z^2=2x\pm2\sqrt{x^2-a^2y}.$$
As usual in this type of problem, $x^2-a^2y$ is a perfect square: in this case, $57^2-40^2\cdot2=49=7^2$. After taking the square root, we end up with $$z=\sqrt{2\cdot57-2\cdot7}=10.$$